# Eclipse Plugin - Notification of when an editor is opened in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, editor

I want to get notified when an editor is opened in Eclipse. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

From [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform/msg51609.html)

> Have your class implement **[`org.eclipse.ui.IPartListener2`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/IPartListener2.html)**.
> Then you get notified when a workbench part (an `IEditorPart`, etc.) just got opened/closed. You can actually filter out which parts you want to pay attention to.

(note: As of 3.5, the IPartListener2 can also implement `IPageChangedListener` to be notified about any parts that implement `IPageChangeProvider` and post `PageChangedEvents`.)

> The tricky part (no pun intended) is to register the listener to workbench.
>
> So, the first thing to do is get a valid `IWorkbenchPage` so that you can call `IWorkbenchPage.addPartListener(<your class that implements IPartListener>)`.

Here is how to get a workbench page.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = null;
IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
if (window != null)
{
    page = window.getActivePage();
}

if (page == null)
{
    // Look for a window and get the page off it!
    IWorkbenchWindow[] windows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
    for (int i = 0; i < windows.length; i++)
    {
        if (windows[i] != null)
        {
            window = windows[i];
            page = windows[i].getActivePage();
            if (page != null)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

See also [here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t112743.html).

---

See [this class](http://www.koders.com/java/fid16CEACC7A2EAD4975C92DBB12EAF9AF43779C75C.aspx?s=IPartListener2#L1061) as an example

```
IPartListener2 partlistener = new IPartListener2(){
        public void partActivated( IWorkbenchPartReference partRef ) {
            if (partRef.getPart(false) == MapEditor.this){
                registerFeatureFlasher();
                ApplicationGIS.getToolManager().setCurrentEditor(editor);
            }
        }
 [...]
```

Or this generic [PartListener](http://www.koders.com/java/fidA5FA750CA43AE027D750F4A7FDD87C9CC91DEC48.aspx?s=IPartListener2#L23) for generic usage of a PartListener2.

Or this [EditorTracker](http://www.koders.com/java/fidE38F000579EA9D103E2620DCA4CECA3187D296E1.aspx?s=IPartListener2#L54)