# Deactivate menu item if editor is not open

Tags: menu, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a menu item in my Eclipse IDE which is want to disable/non-visible if an editor is not currently open.

In the `plugin.xml` I can use the `visibleWhen` code to achieve that, however I don't know how to check if an editor is currently open or not.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030682/eclipse-plugin-notification-of-when-an-editor-is-opened-in-eclipse) talks about a listener to track the editor. However there should be a simpler way to find the editor. For example with `page.getEditorReferences()`. However I can't seem to put all of it together.

So how to poll if the editor is open from the `plugin.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the Ant editor uses.

First an `org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions` definition:

```xml
<extension
       point="org.eclipse.core.expressions.definitions">
    <definition
          id="org.eclipse.ant.ui.activeAntEditor">
       <with
             variable="activeEditorId">
          <equals
                value="org.eclipse.ant.ui.internal.editor.AntEditor">
          </equals>
       </with>
    </definition>
</extension>
```

which defines an expression called `org.eclipse.ant.ui.activeAntEditor` which tests if the active editor is the Ant editor.

Then each menu `command` entry which wants to be visible when the editor is active uses:

```xml
<command
     commandId="org.eclipse.ant.ui.open.declaration.command"
     style="push">
   <visibleWhen
         checkEnabled="false">
     <reference
            definitionId="org.eclipse.ant.ui.activeAntEditor">
     </reference>
   </visibleWhen>
</command>
```

which references the `org.eclipse.ant.ui.activeAntEditor` expression to do the visibility test.